# Match a specific line of text which is NOT followed by another specific line using regex

Tags: regex, eclipse, search

Please help me to figure out the following regex:

I have multiple text files. Some of these files have these two lines of text:

**I am going home soon**

**I am taking a day off tomorrow**

If the first line exist it should be always followed by the second line. But sometimes the second line is missing. I need to search for those occurrences of "I am going home soon" where there is no "I am taking a day off tomorrow" line following after it. I am using File Search in Eclipse. Since it has the regex support I am trying to figure out how I can match a specific line which is not following by another specific line using regex.

Please share your thoughts / solutions about this.
Kind regards.

Comment: What about `I am going home soon

I am taking a day` or `I am going home soon

I am taking a day tommorow` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/f2GWfH/2

`I am going home soon(?=\s+I am taking a day off tomorrow)` Will match

```
I am going home soon.
I am taking a day off tommorow
```

but not just `I am going home soon.` It will match a `I am going home soon.` followed by `I am taking a day off tommorow`.

On the flip-side `I am going home soon(?!\s+I am taking a day off tomorrow)` Will match a `I am going home soon.` that isn't followed by a `I am taking a day off tommorow`

> These are called negative and positive lookaheads.
>
> `a(?=b)` is a positive look ahead, it matches ab, or an a followed by a b.
>
> `a(?!b)` is a negative look ahead, it matches ac, or an a that is not followed by a b.

In your case, the negative lookahead should work perfectly :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! And such a handy online regex tool you linked to the answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @danR :) If it helped remember to upvote and mark as correct!

Comment: Hi Sheshank, I am wondering if you would also know how to do a partial match, e.g. if I know the first line starts with some text, then there is "going home" value somewhere in the middle of the line, then there is some other text till the end of the line. Then the next line also starts with some unknown text, then it would have "taking a day off" somewhere in the middle, then there would be some other text till the end of that line. How in this case I can use the negative look ahead to find the first line when it is not followed by the second line? TIA. Regards. Dan.

Comment: Ok, this seems to be working for me: (going home.*\n)(?!.*not taking a day off)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your message

Comment: @danR Make a new question for it, I can help you

Comment: Hi Sheshank, I just posted a new question for the partial search. I would appreciate if you can post your solution there. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199952/partial-match-with-negative-lookahead-using-regex

Comment: @danR guess someone beat me to it :)

Comment: Ahah )) Yeah, I got some quick answers there. Thanks anyway!