# Partial match with negative lookahead using regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

Using regex with negative lookahead I have to search a text file and identify a partially known line of text that is NOT followed by another partially known line of text. This is a simplified example of the text file:

```
blahblahblah.Name=qwqwqwqwqw
abracadabra.Surname=ererererer
zxzxzxzxzx.Name=kmkmkmkmkmkm
oioioioi.Name=dfdfdfdfdfdf
popopopopopopo.Surname=lklklklklklklk
```

In the sample above you can see the pattern where a line with **Name** should always follow by a line with **Surname**, but sometimes it doesn't happen. I have to identify those "Name lines" which are not followed by the "Surname lines".

I am using File Search in Eclipse (it supports regex).

This is one of my best attempts, I guess, but it still doesn't do the trick:

> (Name.*\n)(?!.*Surname)

Please share your thoughts.
Kind regards.

Comment: Please show your attempts and tag your question with a language or a tool.

Comment: Hi @revo, I just added the info ;)

Comment: Hello, your regex works you only have to do this `(?m)^.*Name.*\n(?!.*Surname)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Good to know that I was so close :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.*\bName=.*\n(?!.*\bSurname=)` will do.

Below is an example in Python.

```
import re
s='''blahblahblah.Name=qwqwqwqwqw
abracadabra.Surname=ererererer
zxzxzxzxzx.Name=kmkmkmkmkmkm
oioioioi.Name=dfdfdfdfdfdf
popopopopopopo.Surname=lklklklklklklk'''
print(re.findall(r'\bName=.*\n(?!.*\bSurname=)', s))
```

This outputs:

```
['zxzxzxzxzx.Name=kmkmkmkmkmkm\n']
```

Comment: `.*\n` won't match on DOS files since `.` won't match either `\n` or `\r`unless you have the `s` flag. Then your lookahead won't work...

Comment: Thanks @blhsing. Would you know how to use Python to search for same across multiple files?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a line oriented negative lookahead:

```
^(.*\.Name.*)[\r\n]+(?!.*\.Surname)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/9g3bVl/1/)

Comment: `\s` doesn't ensure if we are matching a newline character.

Comment: @revo: Fair point. Edited. Bigger point is the `.*\n` won't match a DOS file since `.` won't match line endings.

Comment: In most flavors it does (since dot matches `\r`). Java and a few flavors are exceptions. BTW +1.

Comment: @revo: Your comment sent me scurrying to test if `.` somewhat universally matches `\r`. It seems [mixed](https://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) (read the section *Line Break Characters*. Then testing on Unix, again mixed. `Perl` and `Python` `.` matches `\r` while `awk` and `ruby` does not. Thanks for pointing that out. Still safer to include `\r` in the regex if unknown engine I think. That would be a nasty bug to debug!

Comment: You're welcome. But I didn't reproduce it with Ruby. Maybe a version specific?